# Detach object content from DOM, add other and then append to DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, append, detach

I have this:

```
div#origin
   span
   span

div#final
```

I need to detach the content from "origin", add some extra span's and then append all to "final" with jQuery.

How I can do that. I was searching but maybe I did it with wrong terms because I don't get the answer.

Thanks to any further help.

Comment: so you need to [remove](http://api.jquery.com/remove/), [add](http://api.jquery.com/add/) and [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) ?

Comment: @Jaromanda, all that at the same order. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use append to move the children and the newly defined elements to their new parent element:

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tgm6Y/10575/)

```
var children = $('#origin').children();
var extra = '<span class="extra">Extra Stuff</span>';

// This will move the children to the new parent and add the extra variable defined
$('#final').append(children, extra);
```

---

Another option that could possibly add more flexibility depending on what your needs are is to clone the children and append it when you need to:

[JS Fiddle - clone() and append()](http://jsfiddle.net/Tgm6Y/10577/)

```
var children = $('#origin').children();
var cloned = children.clone(true,true); // Store a copy of the children to be appended
var extra = '<span class="extra">Extra Stuff</span>';

children.remove(); // Remove the old non-cloned children
$('#final').append(cloned, extra); // append cloned and extra elements
```

Comment: "children" save my day. Thanks @Derek Story, that is my answer. :-)

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```js
var data1 = $("#span1").text(),
  data2 = $("#span2").text(),
  other = "Whatever else you wanted"
$("#span1").remove()
$("#span2").remove()
$("#final").append("<span>" + data1 + "</span>")
$("#final").append("<span>" + data2 + "</span>")
$("#final").append("<span>" + other + "</span>")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="orgin">
  <span id="span1">span</span>
  <span id="span2">span</span>
</div>

<div id="final">
</div>
```